# How to compare timestamp in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Given the following table, how can I select the most recent timestamp from a given user?

Here is my table:

[image]

For instance, if USERID 5, I want to compare every USERID 5 timestamp and return the most recent timestamp.

Comment: You can try group by based on userId and select the time and then compare the time using Datediff function.

Comment: This is in the close queue as "unclear what you're asking", but someone managed to figure out what the question meant. The question should be edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly?

Maybe it is just as simple as that?

```
SELECT MAX(CHECKTIME) FROM Table WHERE UserID = 5
```

If not, you could google for `OVER` clause.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the latest timestamp for a user you can use the `max` function:

```
select userid, max(checktime) 
from your_table 
group by userid 
where userid = 5
```

If you remove the `where` clause you'll get a list of all userid with their latest checktime.